# how to call a function from another function in react.js

Tags: reactjs

As you can see that I'm trying to call the showTime function  from setInterval function show that it displays current time ticking without state . But setInterval function is not getting called . How to resolve this issue without using state

=================================================================

```
import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

import Reaxt,{ Component } from 'react';

class  App extends Component {
  showTime=()=>{
    return(
    <h2>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>
    );
  }
 
    render(){
      const name="Shivam" ;
      const i=1;
  return (
    
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world {name}</h1>
         {this.showTime()} 
         {setInterval( this.showTime(),1000)}     
      
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default App;
```

Comment: In React the render function is synchronous and there should be ZERO side-effects, like setting up intervals. Seems you want to simply start a timer and display the current datetime?

Comment: You're calling the function before you pass it to setInterval.

Comment: {setInterval( this.showTime,1000)}

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` ***is*** being called but you've a couple issues:

1. In React the render function is synchronous and there should be ZERO side-effects, like setting up intervals.
2. You are invoking the `this.showTime` callback immediately and passing the return value as the interval callback, which doesn't make sense here.

Seems you want to simply start a timer and display the current datetime. Use `componentDidMount` to start the interval, and `componentWillUnmount` to clear it so you don't attempt to update the state of an unmounted component.

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0 // <-- state to update to trigger rerender
  };

  timerId = null; // <-- interval timer ref so we can clear on unmount

  showTime = () => {
    return <h2>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</h2>;
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState((state) => ({
        count: state.count + 1
      }));
    }, 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  }

  render() {
    // No side-effects!
    const name = "Shivam";

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world {name}</h1>
        {this.showTime()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit how-to-call-a-function-from-another-function-in-react-js]